# undefined local variable or method `author' for #<AuthorsController:0x94c5ee8>

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to submit information into a PHP database and I am getting this error.

**authors_controller.rb**

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @page_title = 'Add New Author'
    @author = Author.new
  end

  def create
    @author = Author.new(author_params)
    @author.save

    redirect_to authors_path
  end

  def update
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
  end

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def author_params 
    params.require(author).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
  end 
end
```

when I click on submit button the error pops up.

Comment: what is a "php database"?

Answer (score 0):

> undefined local variable or method `author' for AuthorsController

The error is in your `author_params` where you have `author` which is treated as *undefined variable*. It should be `:author`(*a symbol*)

```
def author_params
  params.require(:author).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
end
```